# Initializing array from set (Dafny)

Tags: dafny

I know I can do this in Dafny:

```
// uniques is a sequence
var b := new int[|uniques|](i requires 0 <= i < |uniques| => uniques[i]);
```

How is this done if `uniques` is a set?

Comment: What order do you want the array to be in? sets are unordered.

Comment: Assume order doesn't mater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is an easier way, but here's one way:

```
function ArrayToSet<T>(a: array<T>, lo: int, hi: int): set<T>
  reads a
  requires 0 <= lo <= hi <= a.Length
{
  set i | lo <= i < hi :: a[i]
}

method SetToArray<T>(s: set<T>) returns (a: array<T>)
  ensures |s| == a.Length
  ensures s == ArrayToSet(a, 0, a.Length)
{
  if |s| == 0 {
    return new T[0];
  }

  var x :| x in s;

  a := new T[|s|](_ => x);

  var i := 0;
  var t := s;
  while i < |s|
    invariant 0 <= i <= a.Length
    invariant |s| == |t| + i
    invariant s == t + ArrayToSet(a, 0, i)
  {
    label L:
    var y :| y in t;
    a[i] := y;
    assert forall j | 0 <= j < i :: old@L(a[j]) == a[j];
    t := t - {y};
    i := i + 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks. If the language doesn't provide something more convenient, this should probably be in a library... how come there are no libraries in Dafny?

Comment: There is library - https://github.com/dafny-lang/libraries/tree/master. In this there is function SetToSeq which can be used as intermediate step before converting to array

Comment: ah, great. Is there a module system for importing things or is it copy source?

Comment: modules are coming, right now we just released project files, thanks for your patience :-)